# How do I continue with my Typescript build?

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to build an app using jake and I keep getting:

> lib.d.ts not found

Someone pointer me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

> Someone pointer me in the right direction please?

Seems like a *bad install of TypeScript* that *should have `lib.d.ts`* but doesn't.

`lib.d.ts` ships *with typescript*.

[More on `lib.d.ts`](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html)

Comment: Yes you could be right as i have looked in the folders and lib.d.ts is nowhere to be seen.Thank you anyways